# .filter querysets is not displaying data. Django1.11

Tags: python, django

I tried filtering some data using the .filter and it doesn't display. When I try displaying all of them without filtering, it displays everything...but when I try filtering, nothing works.

```
class Part_Time_DM(models.Model):
    Location=models.CharField(max_length=15, default="location")
```

```
def PartFilterView(request):
   qs = Part_Time_DM.objects.all()

   location_query= request.GET.get('location')

   qs = qs.filter(location__icontains=location_query)



   return render(request, 'home.html', {"qs" : qs})
```

```
<!-- Team -->
        <section id="team" class="pb-5">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    {% for fulls in qs %}
                    <!-- Team member -->
                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4">
                        <div class="card two">
                            <img src="{{ fulls.Profile_picture.url }}" alt="John" style="width:40%">
                            <h1>{{fulls.Name}}</h1>
                            <p class="title two">Location : {{fulls.Location}}</p>
                            <br>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <!-- ./Team member -->

                    {% endfor %}

                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
        <!-- Team -->
```

Comment: As far as you show it, your model doesnt have `Profile_picture`  and  `Name` fields. You aslo should do some debugging to understand at which point in your code there is a mistake. Try pringting out  `qs = Part_Time_DM.objects.all()` part, then there might be a problem with getting `location_query`, next you might not even have data to match `location_query`. Take your time and try printing out each step. And be sure to check django docs on naming conventions, we follow them for a reason.

Comment: @bloodwithmilk I have profile picture and the name in my models, I just didn't include them here to avoid making the code very long.

Comment: I would always use `django-filter` rather than rolling my own

Comment: I'd start by finding out exactly what is in `request.GET.get('location')` and whether there really are any objects in the resulting queryset. Or you could check the rest of the code by temporarily assigning `location="known_good_value"`